# slideshow (png+mp4) and faster boot

Tags: raspbian, pi-zero-w, omxplayer, fbi

I have rpi zero w as my photo frame project.

It is an raspberry pi zero w + spi display 320x480 (via framebuffer) and raspbian lite (no X11)

I am using FBI to display images in slideshow manner, and can used mplayer or omxplayer to display videos fine, 
but cant figure out hot to display pngs and mp4 from a folders with random shuffle.
I want to turn of rpi and it starts image slideshow with this command:

```
sudo fbi -u --noverbose -T 1 -t 10 /home/pi/pics/*.png
```

at the end of .bashrc...

Also is there a way to speed up booting?
My boot time is:
Startup finished in 4.336s (kernel) + 17.977s (userspace) = 22.313s
And Blame:

```
8.293s apt-daily.service
      5.959s dev-mmcblk0p2.device
      5.837s hciuart.service
      4.862s networking.service
      4.173s apt-daily-upgrade.service
      3.228s dphys-swapfile.service
      3.150s keyboard-setup.service
      1.940s avahi-daemon.service
      1.916s systemd-logind.service
      1.858s raspi-config.service
      1.611s ssh.service
      1.453s systemd-udev-trigger.service
      1.295s systemd-journald.service
      1.050s systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2dpartuuid-7f4a9df9\x2d01.service
       950ms systemd-fsck-root.service
       909ms triggerhappy.service
       882ms dhcpcd.service
       855ms systemd-udevd.service
       806ms systemd-timesyncd.service
       758ms wifi-country.service
       702ms systemd-remount-fs.service
       700ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
       585ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
```

I need networking, but not at boot, i control everything via ssh, so everything else i could get rid off, but im really green with it, so any help would be great.

Also there custom firmware for faster boot, or similar?

Thanks!!!

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi! Please take the short [Tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [Help Center](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to see how things work here. You should split your question in several single questions.

Answer (score 0):

Unless your project is hosting an Internet server (so security is a concern), you should be able to [get rid of daily updates](https://techpatterns.com/forums/about2673.html) which seem to take a lot of boot time. Another service that takes a lot of time to start is `hciuart` (that is, Bluetooth), so if you don't use BT consider removing the stack (AFAIK that's `bluez` and `bluetooth` packages and their dependencies).